# Case Status at a Specific Time

Tags: civicase

I'm on Drupal 7 and CiviCRM 5.10 (yes, I'll update to 5.12 this weekend). I have a case with multiple case status: Active, Maintenance, Closed. When case activities are entered in the system, it doesn't seem to save the case status at the time the case activity is entered. For example:

- 4/26/19 Case Opened
- 4/26/19 Client meeting
- 4/28/19 Case status changed from active to maintainence
- 4/30/19 Housing visit
- 4/31/19 Housing visit

If I were to create a Views report of the case activities, I see that the case status for 4/26/19 is labeled "Maintenance" but it should "Active" (which is the case status at the time it was entered).

Does anyone know how I could create a report and pull the case status AT the time of the activities entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to base it on the entire history of activity subjects which is a bit tricky. I'm not sure how to do it in a drupal view.

In pseudocode it would be something like SELECT ChangeCaseStatus activity with MAX(date) earlier than activity date currently being output. If null then Active.

Comment: Hmm.. haven't figured it out yet. I don't see an option to see the entire history of activity subjects. Seems like when I pull case activities, it is already set to the most recent status.

Comment: Yeah I don't know how you'd do this in a drupal view. I usually do case reporting separately, so that you have access to run your own SQL where needed.